# Sync Customers even when deleted in Quickbooks with qbXML

Tags: quickbooks

I synched a customer from my SaaS application into quickbooks using qbXML and web connector, I used the field ExternalGUID to be able to associate it to my internal customer in my application.

The customer synched fine in Quickbooks.  But I am still testing my application, so I deleted the customer in quickbooks just to test my code again and be able to sync back the customer in Quickbooks.

But now when I try to add the customer I just deleted, I get this response from quickbooks:

Quickbooks doesn't seem to clear the item from the list of used ExternalGUID.  How can I make sure the customer is re-added to quickbooks when I am using the same ExternalGUID again?

I am using the US desktop edition of quickbooks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use the ExternalGUID- there are issues with it, and it doesn't support older QuickBooks versions.

Your best bet is to store a link between the ListID and your internal application ID in your own application.